# Unable to use /etc/aliases to feed incoming mails to custom program

Tags: postfix

In my Mac, this is what I followed:

1. Following is the ruby file I'm testing with. This is capable of reading from STDIN and write in a file sample.mail:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env ruby

    while line = STDIN.gets    
        f = File.open("/Users/username/sample.mail", "a+")    
        f.puts line    
        f.close    
    end
   ```
2. Edited  `/etc/aliases` and added this line:

   ```
   username: "|/Users/username/stdinpipe.rb"
   ```
3. Edited `/etc/postfix/main.cf`  and added this line

   ```
   allow_mail_to_commands = alias,forward,include
   ```
4. Used `sudo newaliases` to sore the changes.

Now, at this stage I am expecting when I send a mail to username@localhost it should be appended to `/Users/username/sample.mail`.

But it's not happening.

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: What is in postfix logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, postfix in OS X does not have any alias_maps specified. You need to make sure that this line is not commented out in main.cf:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
```

Also, the script must be executable by the _postfix user. The file you want to write to must be owned and writable by the _postfix user

After those are corrected you need to reload postfix: sudo postfix reload

Comment: Great, thanksalot :)

I had to restart the postfix daemon with 

`sudo launchctl stop org.postfix.master` followed by `sudo launchctl start org.postfix.master`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to ensure that the script is made executable.  IE, run chmod a+x on the script.  Also, your alias example line has a capital "/Users", which is non-conventional and unix respects case in paths and files (unlike windows), so make sure the case matches.

If that fails, you might replace the "#!/usr/bin/env ruby" with "#!/usr/bin/ruby" (or wherever your ruby is located).

Comment: On a Mac, the /Users folder is in fact with a capital U. However, by default the filesystem on a Mac is not case sensitive.